# Showing posts of a term under a custom taxonomy of a custom post

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I created a custom post `Electronics`. Then `Electronics` have a custom taxonomy `appliences`. And `appliances` have terms like `home appliances`, `kitchen appliances`, etc. Now `home appliances` have some posts.

Now I want to show posts under the `home appliances` term. I have created a page `taxonomy-appliances.php`.

```
---- Electronics (custom post)
      |__ appliances (custom taxonimy)
          |__home appliances
             |__ posts
             |
          |__Kitchen appliances
             |_posts
```

How I can show it in that page?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    $args = array(
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'appliances',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'home appliances',
                )
            )
        );
    $posts = new WP_Query($args);

    if($posts->have_posts()){
        while ($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post();

            echo get_the_title();

        endwhile;
    }

?>
```

But nothing is showing

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'electronics', // your post type name
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'appliances', //your taxonomy name
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => 'home-appliances',//here use the slug, check the slug of your term

    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this, 

  $posts_array = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'appliances',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'home-appliances',
            )
        )
    )
);
```